# steel poles with pine shelving - how to fix?

Tags: pipe, furniture, shelving

[image]I have little setup that i didnt properly think about it! rush job.

I have four Galvanised poles with four pine shelves (900x220x20) sitting on gate-eye tube clamps. The poles go through the wood on the corner after i cut the holes. Pipe is 33.7mm, i cut the holes 35mm thinking the wiggle room would help. It has not.

they just rest on top and as you can guess the whole thing is unstable and joggles around.

Without getting a bit more pipe and fixing the top to the wall (i rent, not allowed) how could I make the structure more secure.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is there's nothing holding the 4 posts in place.  The fix is to attach the shelves to the posts as tightly as possible - they can't just set on the posts.  What you've basically done is tried to create a large version of these common steel shelves:

[image]

If you've ever put one together, the strength and stability comes from the wedge anchors on each corner holding the shelves tightly in place.

Your unit's stability is proportional to how tight you can attach each shelf to each corner.  Any looseness will be notices in wobble.

I'm not familiar with the brackets you say that you are using, but you could possibly sandwich the shelves between two brackets (one on top, one on bottom, but they'd have to make a very tight sandwich).  Or if it's like a pipe flange maybe the shelf can be securely screwed to the brackets.  The point is, you have to have a tight, secure connection on each corner of each shelf.

Answer (score 1):

As @ JPhi1618 has stated try adding a second clamp on the top of the shelves. Before trying that I would  try bolting the shelves to the smaller hinge pin hole. For visual appearance sake I would try either a carriage bolt or a flat head screw that is counter sunk.